# Not able to retrieve sum of varchar column using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var a = 123;
var query = (from p in a where p.ID == a) //gives 10 records.
.Sum(Convert.Int32.Parse(x => x.balance); // this line gives the following message.
```

Error Message.
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32 (System.String)',

Database design for the varchar column can't change to int or double.

Comment: your code makes very little sense. what's it even supposed to actually _do_?

Comment: Why persist a numeric value as a string to begin with? Types exist for a reason, use them. Match the appropriate type with the expected values. Example: If you want to store a moment in time you should use a Date type (DateTime in .net, DateTime2 in sql server, etc). If you want to store a balance use a decimal type. A name would be a unicode string, a code could be an ascii string, the list goes on.

Comment: What you probably mean is either `Convert.ToInt32(...)` or `int.Parse(...)`.

Comment: I am new student. a varchar column contains numeric value and want to calculate as a sum or total using linq query. First part of query works fine return all records that match particular id's. second part is the calculate / sum or total of another column in the same table.

Comment: `"I am new student. a varchar column contains numeric value ..."` ← Do not use varchar to store a balance, use a numeric type like decimal. Then you can execute calculations on the stored values like sum (for example).

Comment: @igor. at this time cannot change the design of db.is it possible to use convert method in linq and sum the column in varchar. Kindly share any single working example.

Comment: If you are not allowed to change the schema please include that in your question as that is relevant.

Comment: @ Franz Gleichmann. any example will be highly appreciated. convert method in linq and sum the column values which is in varchar type.

Comment: @Igor. I have updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion appreciated.

Comment: What version of LINQ to EF are you using: EF 6.x, EF Core 1.x, EF Core 2.0, EF Core 2.1, EF Core 3.x?

Comment: (a) Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 - Version 15.8.2. (b) .Net Framework 4.7.03062. (c) EF v4.0.30319. (d) EF Core <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = 123; 
var sum = (from p in a where p.ID == a) //gives 10 records. 
             .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.balance));

var sum = (from p in db.table where p.ID == a)
             .AsEnumerable() // @juharr's suggestion
             .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.balance));
```

You want to convert the string in each iteration.. not the loop itself

This assumes the balance is a string and not an int already

Comment: is it possible to use convert method in linq and sum the column in varchar. Kindly share any single working example.

Comment: @NadeemTaj added another example using `Convert.ToInt32()` method instead of `int.Parse()`

Comment: It's not working and getting LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32 (System.String)'.  Anyway appreciated for your time and help. I am not certain but feel and it looks like dealing with bug in LINQ when it comes to these three things together (Sum, Convert on varchar columns).

Comment: @NadeemTaj It's not a bug, EF has to translate code into SQL and does not support translating everything.  One option is if you do a `AsEnumerable` before the `Sum` then it will pull the rows into memory and the conversion will happen in code rather than on the DB.

Comment: @NadeemTaj Added juharrs suggestion to the example above of using AsEnumerable before the Sum

Comment: This sample is useful in term of working with the conversion. @Juharr. Let me re-phrase the statement. It's not a bug but it is un-handled issue with conversion in LINQ. And would like to thank you to the community for their time and suggestions to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If Entity Framework (or Linq-to-SQL, not sure what ORM are you using) can't translate something to SQL syntax, you can always try to resolve the query "C#-side" or client-side.

If you add `.ToList()` before the `.Sum()`, that should force the query to resolve on the database, and then the `.Sum(...)` and the `.ToInt32()` will be executed in memory.

```
var sum = (from p in db.table where p.ID == a)
             .ToList()
             .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.balance));
```